# How to extract the embedded/preview image from a link in C#?

Tags: c#, image, preview

Im building a C# program that shows the news feed from a RSS XML page and I want to include a feature that shows a link, the title (Which I already have) and the image preview of that link like it happens on Discord, or Messenger.

If we send a link of a post, for example, and that post has a image, it will show a preview (+/- like the pictures). Same happens for Youtube links, it shows the tumbnail of the video.

Here is an example of a link from a post on Discord and Messenger.
It displays the "main picture" of that post.

Discord example: http://prntscr.com/n8j0m6

Messenger example: http://prntscr.com/n8j29f

I want to extract the embedded/preview image from a link in C# or at least the link of that image (So I can then load it in the program) or create a similar preview system. That would be even better. But with the image link, I can create a method to do that automatically.

I havent had any luck finding anything similar so far. Maybe I am not using the correct term.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: it's the `<meta property="og:image" content="(...)">` tag under the `<head>` tag.

Comment: I am sorry, my app is being made in WinForms.

Comment: So? Download the page, check the html. You can do that from WinForms.

Comment: I just thought there was a different way to do it. Thank You.